# Найти предложения с ошибками

Tags: грамотная-речь, типы-ошибок

Каждый может допустить ошибку, главное — вовремя её исправить.
Укажите, пожалуйста, предложения с ошибками.

1) Вошёл юноша лет двадцати, в очках, с портфелем.

2) Теплоход плыл по широкому Миссисипи.

3) Он искал в газетах объявления о свободных вакансиях.

4) В скором времени он должен опубликовать новый рассказ или очерк.

5) Мать с детьми уехала в деревню.

Comment: Укажите, пожалуйста, свой вариант.

Comment: Думаю 2 )предложение

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В первом предложении, возможно, пропущена запятая после слова юноша, т.к. идёт уточнение: юноша (какой?) лет двадцати.
Второе предложение. Миссисипи — это река, ж.р., отсюда следует: не по широкому, а *по широкой*.
Третье предложение. Вакансия — это уже сама по себе не занимаемая должность, т.е. свободная. Так что слово "свободных" здесь явно лишнее.

Comment: "Вошёл юноша лет двадцати, в очках, с портфелем".  Katya Rodionova, здесь не надо запятой. Первое несогласованое определение относится к слову с неопределенным значением "юноша" и определяет его, а остальные два несогласованных определения имеют уточняющий характер.

Comment: Ну я же написала, что ВОЗМОЖНО, а не точно 100%. Я всё-таки опираюсь на вариант, что это уточнение, относящееся к слову "юноша", а остальные 2  к слову "вошёл".

Comment: Думаю, что все три определения относятся к  существительному "юноша", но значение уточнения имеют только два. Для сравнения: Подошел экскурсовод, в темных очках, с портфелем. Здесь все определения уточняющие.

Answer (score 3):

2) Теплоход плыл по *широкой* (реке) Миссисипи.

3) Он искал в газетах объявления о вакансиях. (*Свободные вакансии* - скрытая тавтология.)